# Is there a way to replace all system.out/err and e.printstacktraces with logger in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, netbeans-7

Is there a feature in netbeans that'll let me easily config and replace all occurrences of "system.out" and "e.printstacktrace" to "logger.info/error/log" ?

I used find/replace to get rid of all the "system.out"s, and now i need to get rid of all the "printstacktraces", I can probably write a parser and read all my java files. But before I do that I just want to know if something like this is already implemented in netbeans, currently in netbeans 7.1 hints, they only show you where these things are, but I couldn't find an option for code refactoring.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use find/replace for printStackTrace?  Or vim or sed?  Personally I would use find/grep/vim for this.

Comment: You don't have any access to other IDE as Eclipse?

Comment: to jahroy: because I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I figured something like this should already be implemented in netbeans.
If netbeans really can't do this, then that's probably what I will do.

Comment: to pier: yes I do have access to Eclipse, but I don't want to port my whole project to another IDE just for this.

Comment: Fair enough... I'm only recommending it because you mention `write a parser`.  Using find/grep/sed or find/grep/vim seems pretty quick and simple to me... There must not be a way to do it with NetBeans, since this question comes up often.

Comment: to jahroy: I ended up writing a regex find/replace for this. I was out of my mind when I said I needed a parser, going to accept your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will open each .java file that contains `printStackTrace` in vim.

Of course you can substitute vim with your text editor of choice:

```
alias javafind='find . -name '\''*.java'\'' -print | xargs fgrep -il'
vim `javafind printStackTrace`
```

The first command creates an alias that returns all java files (starting in the current directory) that contain the first argument.

The second command says: open each file that contains the term `printStackTrace` with vim.

An even better solution would be to use sed to intelligently search/replace with a regex.